# Odd-even margin

Tags: margins, double-sided, geometry

I am writing a book and I need to set the odd/even margin on the binding side.

```
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=1cm, right=1cm, headsep=14pt]{geometry}
```

I need `left = 2.1cm` for odd pages and for even one `left = 1.0cm`.

I found

```
\oddsidemargin
\evensidemargin
```

but those change all four sides.

How can I set two different margins on odd/even pages?

Comment: There is actually an option `bindingoffset` for the package `geometry`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this with the `inner` and `outer` keys. The inner (outer) margin is the left (right) margin on odd pages and right (left) margin on even pages.
Hence

```
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, outer=1cm, inner=2.1cm, headsep=14pt]{geometry}
```

should do what you want.

As mentioned in comments below, the `twoside` option must also be added, either to the documentclass or `geometry`. The `book` class has this by default, while `report` and `article` does not.

Comment: What happens if you set innter and outer but don't pick twosided?

Comment: @DanielSank It would have taken you less time to just test that yourself, rather than wait for my reply ... The inner margin will be the left, the outer the right. `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[outer=1cm, inner=5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum\lipsum
\end{document}`

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing a "report",
then

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[left=2in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TEXSE, could you clarify how could a report class be used for book? The OP stated clearly in their question that they wish to use book.

Comment: @Raaja actually the OP didn't specify the `book` documentclass, they just said they are writing a book - which you can also do with a twosided report as in this answer.

Comment: @Marijn sorry I understood that as a book class.