# custom template change of leftmargin and rightmargin on new page

Tags: margins

I have using own custom `LaTeX Class file` and how to change the `oddside` and `evenside` margin in the new `page` to `End of the document`. I'm not possible to use `\newgeometry` options because more development is used my own `LaTeX class file`. I have tried [Odd-even margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98861/odd-even-margin), [If Then Else for odd page/even page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6143/if-then-else-for-odd-page-even-page) but unable to get my requirement.

My Requirement is if `oddpage` need to give `\leftskip50pt or \leftmargin50pt` and if `evenpage` need to give `\leftskip10pt or \leftmargin10pt`. I have using `XeLaTeX` packages are `tikz`, `pgz`, `tcolorbox` etc.

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[textwidth=450pt,textheight=600pt,left=50mm,right=50mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[a3]{crop}
\voffset=60pt
\hoffset=60pt
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{quote}
               {\list{}{\leftmargin50pt\rightmargin60pt}%
                \item\relax}
               {\endlist}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\mygraphics}[3][]{%
  \tcbincludegraphics[nobeforeafter,
    blanker,hbox,
    minipage boxed title*=-6mm,
    title={\captionsetup{skip=0pt}\captionof{figure}    {#3}},
    attach boxed title to bottom center,
    boxed title style={enhanced,size=title,sharp corners,
      boxrule=0pt,frame hidden,colback=green!50!black!    25},
    #1]{#2}%
}

\newsavebox\mysavebox

\newenvironment{textbyfigure}[1]{%
  \sbox{\mysavebox}{#1}%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[blanker,
    beforeafter skip=5pt,
    sidebyside,sidebyside gap=5mm,
    sidebyside align=top,
    righthand width=\wd\mysavebox,]%
}{%
  \tcblower%
  \raisebox{\the\dimexpr-\ht\mysavebox-\dp\mysavebox+\baselineskip/2\relax}    {\usebox{\mysavebox}}%
  \end{tcolorbox}
}
\crop
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{textbyfigure}{
  \mygraphics{drawer.png}
    {The Roman numerals on this stone show the distance     to the next village.}}
Throughout the ages and in different countries, number     systems were developed
and used to help people count and communicate with     numbers. From the ancient
Egyptians to the modern day, different systems have     used pictures and symbols to
represent whole numbers. Some of the well-known     number systems are the Egyptian,
Babylonian, Roman, modern Chinese and the Hindu-    Arabic or decimal system.
\end{textbyfigure}

\lipsum[2]

\newpage
\begin{quote}
\lipsum[3-15]
\end{quote}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's not an MWE. Please post an example which will compile. I don't understand what you mean by switching in the middle of the page.

Comment: Perhaps ypu should say what your intended outcome is. it doesn't make sense to change \oddsidemargin mid page as it is used in setting up the page head and foot. However you can simply change the visual margin by using a list environment, see the definition of `quote` in `article.cls` which increases left and right margin, but other variants are possible

Comment: @cfr: I have required `newpage` and not a middle of the page. For Example, Page No. 1 and 2 `leftmargin` is `50pt` and `rightmargin` is `50pt` and Page 3 onwards `leftmargin` need `75pt` and `rightmargin` is `85pt`.

Comment: @David: I have check `quote` environment but it's changing globally same size only. But my requirement is Page No 3 `leftmargin` should be `50pt` and Page No 4 `leftmargin` should be `85pt`. How to achieve this? I have updated my question.

Comment: It's not really possible as text is typeset before tex decides which page it will be on. the page breaker can move an entire page left or right (hence oddsidemargin and evensidemargin) but you can not do that mid page

Comment: @David: Thanks for your info. and one small doubt, using `\newgeomentry` we can able to change `oddsidemargin` and `evensidemargin` when starting `new page` in the `document`.

Comment: yes but that is at a forced page break the page break is forced for exactly that reason, you can not change mid page

Comment: @David: My requirement is also the same. But i cann't use `\newgeomentry` options because my own LaTeX template is having some automation scripts. It's possible any other way?

Comment: your stated requirement is to do it "in the middle of a page" which isn't possible, if that is not what you meant I suggest you edit the question

Comment: @David: Updated my question.